# clicking on link through ref created with React.useRef issuing Illegal invocation error message

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to fetch data, build a csv from the data, and then download it with one click, but unfortunately, I'm only able to get as far as storing the data in state.  The code is as follows with a mockAPI:

```
import React, {useState, useRef, useEffect} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {CSVLink} from 'react-csv'
import get from 'lodash.get';
import isEmpty from 'lodash.isempty'

function App() {
  const csvLink = useRef();
  const [state, setState] = useState({data:[], headers: []});
  useEffect(() => {
    const clicker = get(csvLink, 'current.link.click');
    !isEmpty(state.data) && clicker && clicker();
  }, [state])
  const mockFetch = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const headers = ['name', 'age']
      const data = [{name:'foo', age: 30},{name: 'bar', age: 40}]
      setState({data, headers})
    },0)
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <p onClick={mockFetch}>click me</p>
      <div style={{display:'none'}}>
      <CSVLink
          headers={state.headers}
          data={state.data}
          filename="data.csv"          
          ref={csvLink}
       />
       </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at get-csv.js
    at commitHookEffectList (react-dom.development.js:17283)
    at commitPassiveHookEffects (react-dom.development.js:17307)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:149)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:199)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:256)
    at commitPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:18774)
    at wrapped (scheduler-tracing.development.js:207)
    at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:18822)
    at dispatchAction (react-dom.development.js:13530)
```

Comment: `clicker` need to be trigger inside of `onClick` function scope. But you trigger it in `useEffect` which is outside of `onClick` scope. That's why you get the error

Comment: can you advise on how to refactor this to get the desired behavior?

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. The problem is you call `click` function of `<a>` via reference `clicker`. You need to call it directly `csvLink.current.link.click()` instead.